# How to name values that are displayed on utility meters?

Tags: word-request

How to name values that are displayed on utility meters?

[image]

Please consider using this term in sentences like:

> I need to tell **XXX** to the inspector.
>
> When we moved from here **XXX** were 164m^3 of cold water, 86m^3 of hot water and 1026 kWh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term most often used to describe the numbers shown on a utility meter is a **meter reading**.

> I need to tell my meter reading to the inspector.
>
> When we moved from here meter readings were 164m^3 of cold water,
>   86m^3 of hot water and 1026 kWh of electricity.

As the examples above suggest, the term can be used for your electricity meter, water meter, gas meter, and so on.